# Dynamically updating events list in Android Weekview library

Tags: android, calendar, android-library

I am implementing Android weekView library to show bookings on calender view. 
I want to update the bookings from server when month changes on the view.

https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View

Thanks in advance.